# Columns of 1 data table become additional headers on another data.frame

Tags: r, header

One data table is generated via:

```
q <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), replicate(10,sample(50:100,5,rep=TRUE))))
```

and another:

```
y <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10), replicate(2,sample(1:5,10,rep=TRUE))))
```

Renaming columns names in y,

```
colnames(y) <- c("size", "category")
```

Am trying to add *two more header lines* to q, using the columns in y - the heading "category" (with integers) would be the (new) second line, with heading "size" (with integers) the third new line.

My output should look something like this per screenshot (first 5 lines only)-

[image]

The output shows an ID column (x-axis), and X1, X2, X3.... (y1, y2, y3... values).  Between ID and X1 can be seen the 2 new headers, Category and Size.  I think this will require a new column, so as not to encroach on the ID column.

Thx

Comment: Can you show us a desired output? It is not clear to me based on what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here you go:

```
q <- rbind(c(colnames(y[2]),y[,2]),c(colnames(y[1]),y[,1]), q)
```

**After edits:**

```
# same as above plus some new column
q <- rbind(c(NA,colnames(y[2]),y[,2]),c(NA,colnames(y[1]),y[,1]), cbind(q[,1], NA, q[,2:11]))

# add column names
colnames(q)[1:2] <- c("ID","new_col")
```

Comment: Given your edits, this should be what you have wanted. Let me know by accepting (or not) this answer.

Comment: Pascal, almost, thx.  On the output, X1 is the x-axis, with X2... the y values.  My fault for not saying that a new column is needed, to indicate the two new headers, category and size.  In the absence of this, X1 contains category, size, and y-values.  I hope this is not too difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow. I guess your desired output (screenshot) is then actually not your final output?

Comment: I will modify my original query, that might be useful

Comment: This is more clear now. I changed the code accordingly.